# PostgreSQL: Timestamp in the future

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

How can I get a timestamp with a date 30 days from now?

I tried things like now() + integer '30'... but it didn't work.

I'm running Postgres 8.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT NOW() + '30 days'::interval
```

Comment: FWIW, the syntax `interval '30 days'` also works [as of 8.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-datetime.html).

Comment: Yep... and for 9.1 `now() + '30 days'` also works, I haven't checked that for earlier versions.

Comment: Any chance we might be able to also add how this might be correctly implemented when setting default values for a table?

Answer (score 8):

The standard SQL expression is

```
select current_timestamp + interval '30' day
```

Quotes around the number, not around the phrase. See [the earliest SQL standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) I can find online, p 91. PostgreSQL is much more flexible than the standard, which can be a good thing or a bad thing. I support a lot of different dbms--the flexibility hurts me more often than it helps. PostgreSQL, for example, supports this non-standard statement.

```
select current_timestamp + interval '1 month, 2 days, 3 hours, 2 minutes';
```

Comment: +1 for using the standard dialect unless there is a compelling reason to deviate. Makes it easier to switch back and forth with other SQL flavors.