# How do I insert future timestamp in postgres

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, future

I see [select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914080/postgresql-timestamp-in-the-future) in this example, but when I try to do a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO "public"."sessions"
    ("account", "token_key", "timestamp", "timeout") 
VALUES
    ('zndr.k.94@gmail.com', 'afasdfasdf', 'now()', 'now()' + (20 * interval '1 minute')) 
RETURNING "id", "account", "token_key", "timestamp", "timeout", "active", "keychain";
```

I'm not sure what to do. Can't find any examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does it.

```
INSERT INTO 'public'.'sessions'('account', 'token_key', 'timestamp', 'timeout') 
VALUES('abc@123.com', 'afakjljksdasdfasdffasdf', NOW(), NOW() + '20 minutes');
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your answer in PostgreSQL 9.6.2. It yields a syntax error.
Is this answer still considered current for Postgres 9.x?

Comment: @ajxs Possibly might need to remove the double quotes.